# Extract two patterns at once using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings, each with the following pattern (a set of words  followed by parentheses enclosing comma separated words):

```
"vw xy zz (X, Y, Z)"
```

My desired output is:

```
["vw xy zz", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

I know how to extract the text before the parentheses:

```
import re
pattern = r"(^[^\(]+)"
text = "vw xy zz (X, Y, Z)"
re.findall(pattern, text)
# ['vw xy zz ']
```

I also know how to extract the text between the parentheses:

```
pattern = r"\(.*\)"
text = "vw xy zz (X, Y, Z)"
re.findall(pattern, text)
# ['(X, Y, Z)']
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to combine the patterns to get the desired output all at once.

Comment: `re.findall(r'[^(),\s](?:[^(),]*[^(),\s])?', s)` - all at once with no need to trim the items. Allows any chars but parentheses and commas. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r6tYqM/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values are not alphanumeric only, and may contain any chars but whitespaces and commas, I suggest usign a "generic" regex based on negated character classes:

```
re.findall(r'[^(),\s](?:[^(),]*[^(),\s])?', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r6tYqM/1).

There is no need to `strip()` the items after the `re.findall` returns all the matches.

**Details**

- `[^(),\s]` - a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char but `(`, `)`, `,` and whitespace
- `(?:[^(),]*[^(),\s])?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[^(),]*` - any chars but `(`, `)` and `,`
  - `[^(),\s]` - any char but `(`, `)`, `,` and whitespace

Comment: great answer :)

Comment: best one this will match what you want exactly

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\s?){3}|[A-Z]/g

const text = "vw xy zz (X, Y, Z)"
const res = text.match(regex);
console.log(res)
```

this regex will match : `["vw xy zz ", "X", "Y", "Z"]`

you can test it here [regex tester](https://regexr.com/)

```
([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\s){3}|[A-Z]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
s = "vw xy zz (X, Y, Z)"
result = [i.strip() for i in re.findall('[\w\s]+', s)]
```

Output:

```
['vw xy zz', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```